# apply translation using gettext .po files

Tags: localization, gettext

Okay, this should be simple, but I can't find the information I need.

Let's say I created .po file from some text file (which is not a source code).
I translated needed strings.

How do I apply this .po file? In other words what software should I use to replace strings in a given text file based on the existing .po file?

I expect this to be a commandline utility or gui-based that can do this in a batch for hundreds of files.

Edit: oh, forgot one important thing. This is for Windows!

Comment: Did you solve this? I asked a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246851/how-to-make-translations-of-full-articles-from-po-files-in-sphinx-or-gettext

Answer (score 1):

[polib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polib) can, with a bit of glue code, be used to manipulate .po files in batch mode.

Comment: Could you please expand on the *glue code*? In polib API I can't see functions that could help with the question's author problem. (https://polib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)