# How to make translations of full articles from po files in Sphinx or gettext

Tags: internationalization, python-sphinx, gettext

I'm writing a project documentation in Sphinx. I want to make translations of my `.rst` files, and I generated and translated `.po` files. Sphinx generates `html` translations fine, but I want to have `.rst` or markdown full articles (to use them on another site).

How can I recreate `.rst` or markdown files with translations from these `.po` (or `.mo`) files?

Sphinx, gettext or Python solutions will suit.
I tried to find information about that, but most answers concern translation of a string, not of a complete article.

Comment: I found only one question, which asks about the same (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766089/apply-translation-using-gettext-po-files), but I wonder whether a better solution has appeared since 7 years, and whether there is a known solution for Sphinx.

Comment: I prefer a general and "default" solution, but if it doesn't exist, then a script or 3rd party project is better than nothing.

Comment: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/manage-translations.html

Comment: @StevePiercy thanks, I just used that. But it generates html, not rst or markdown. This is the problem.

Comment: I think you skipped over the part where it describes the process to create translatable messages using two methods in your documentation source files.

Comment: @StevePiercy sorry, I don't understand you. Could you please give a link to the exact subsection of the doc? In the beginning of your link the overview is "1) Create translatable files (.pot and .po extensions) from source language 2) Translate the text on those files from source language to target language 3) Build the documentation in target language using the translated texts" - it builds `html` docs, but there are no `rst` files in the process. I read this and another manual (https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/localization.html), but didn't find the answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally asked this question on the `sphinx-users` official mailing list. That one is really active and good. Matt from Documatt gave the following answer (with my small rewriting):

There is no direct way. Such a tool is on Docutil's [todo list](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/tools.html#restructuredtext-generating-tools) too. Just the idea that might help:

1. [Build](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinx.builders.xml.XMLBuilder) your Sphinx to Docutils XML. For example, if you have French localization (fr), then

   sphinx-build -b xml source_dir output_dir -D language="fr"

   in your project root.
2. Use Docutils's tool [xml2rst](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/sandbox/xml2rst/).

The author of `xml2rst` also gave [svn](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/docutils/code/trunk/sandbox/xml2rst) and [sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/sandbox/xml2rst/) links to the code.

That worked indeed. There was a problem with extra whitespaces, however. They appeared during creation of the XML, and they threaten a well-formed rst (the xml2rst doesn't erase them). I'm going to delete them manually (this is not a big problem, any decent editor or `sed` can do that).